# UITableView EditingStyle clear button hides

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently creating my `TableView`, but I'm finding some problems with the `EditingStyle` and a `TextField` in the `UITableViewCell`.

So basically, the `UITableView` is set to `EnableEditing` for true at the beginning, so users can easily delete the dynamic content they are giving in the `UITextFields` in my `UITableViewCells`.

But the problem now is, by enabling the editing mode from my `TableView` the Clear button of the Textfield goes to the right. Is there a way that i can solve this?

The second picture is from my Storyboard. I've aligned the `UITextField` right to the Cell.

[image: Cell image of clear button.]
[image: Cell image of clear button.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used AutoLayout for making the constraints. Worked well now

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the UITextField Class and override this method

```
- (CGRect)clearButtonRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x - 30, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But it was to hard to get it right on this way. Did it with AutoLayout.